# Converting While Loop to For Loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How would I convert this while loop to a for loop?

```
while(continue()){
    printf("test")
}
```

Comment: You should add language tag such as `c`

Comment: In C, `while(x)` .. is the equivalent of `for(; x;)` ..

Comment: Have you read about for loops? What's stopping you from doing the conversion?

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't, really, the `while` loop is the best construct for that particular use case. A `for` loop has a setup step, continuation condition, and post-iteration step, and you only need the second of those (which is what `while` uses anyway).

But, if you *really* wanted to do this, it would be something like:

```
for(;continue();)
```

It's not something I, or probably *any* sane person, would do :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most of people would prefer while in this case, but for would look like this:

```
for(;continue();) 
{
  printf("test");
}
```