# Is it possible to rewrite this while loop that uses an iteration function as a for loop?

Tags: c++, c

I have a while loop that looks something like this:

```
int index = 0;
Foo foo = getFooAtIndex(index);

while(foo != NULL_FOO_VALUE) {
    // do stuff with foo
    index++;
    foo = getFooAtIndex(index);
}
```

Is there any way to rewrite this as a more compact for loop?

C++ answers are appreciated, but I'd most like something that would work in C. So that would preclude doing something like writing a function that uses this pattern to construct and return something like a vector of `Foo`s and then iterating over that.

edit: Some more information:

Assume `getFooAtIndex()` is someone else's API that I'm stuck with. It's the only method I have of getting `Foo` and it has to be by index. There's no way for me to know how many `Foo`s I'm going to get.

The sort of `for` loop I'm after would allow me to call `continue` from anywhere in the loop and still have it work correctly, eventually iterating over every `Foo` until `getFooAtIndex()` returns a null value.

Comment: Add a getNumberOfElements() function?  Without more context we're left with wild guessing.  For some APIs the answer will be yes, for some it will be no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting While Loop to For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492900/converting-while-loop-to-for-loop)

Comment: @mkrieger1 No it doesn't. That's a much simpler case than mine.

Comment: It's rather for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @273 In the current form the code above would likely be closed as [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652). Please take time to read over [what is on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Can you say where this would this be on topic? It's been summarily rejected here for reasons I do not understand, given this is a specific programming question with a specific answer. There isn't any more context to the question than what I originally asked, and the code would be almost identical if I replaced `getFooAtIndex` with the specific, very niche API I'm using. I'm just trying to find a better way of writing this loop.

Comment: @BriBri take a peak at [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This [similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266562/use-of-for-loop-conditional-statement-unrelated-to-iterating-variable/266567#266567) has a little bit more context.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is to use `for` when the quantity of iterations is known; use `while` when the iteration depends on a condition.

Comment: One option is `Foo foo; for (int index = 0; (foo = getFooAtIndex(index++)) != NULL_FOO_VALUE; ) {/* do stuff with foo */ }`.     The reliance on side-effects in the loop condition is considered poor form by some though, although it is well defined.

Comment: @Peter `foo` would need to be initialized. And why not move the side effects to the point in the loop where they're supposed to go, e.g. `for(Foo foo = getFooAtIndex(0); foo != NULL_FOO_VALUE; foo = getFooAtIndex(++index))`?

Comment: @BriBri  There is no problem with initialisation.   The first call of `getFooAtIndex()` occurs before the loop body, because the loop condition in a  `for` loop is evaluated/tested once before the body is executed the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I would typically see:

```
Foo foo;
for (int index = 0; 
        (foo = getFooAtIndex(index)) != NULL_FOO_VALUE;
        index++) {
    // do stuff with foo
}
```

But `getFooAtIndex` is a bad api, that usually has to traverse the whole collection. It's much better to use and implement `fooIterator` or similar interface.

```
for (FooIterator foo = fooBegin(); 
        foo != fooEnd();
        fooIteratorInc(&foo)) {
    Foo foo = fooIteratorGet(&get);
    // do stuff with foo
}
```

Comment: `getFooAtIndex` is not my function, as I don't have control over the API. I'm forced to use it and there are no other methods I can use to get `Foo`s.

Comment: Alternatively: `index=0; while(foo=getFooAtIndex(index++) != NULL_FOO_VALUE) {...}`, but you have to keep in mind that inside the loop `index` is one higher than you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most succinct way of doing it I've found yet:

```
int index = 0;
for(Foo foo = getFooAtIndex(0); foo != NULL_FOO_VALUE; foo = getFooAtIndex(++index)) {
    // do stuff with foo. It's safe to use continue
}
```

One of the advantages of this is that there are no side effects in the for loop's condition; the iteration happens appropriately in the iteration expression.

If `Foo` turns out to be an integer type, and it's guaranteed to be able to represent any possible index we might pass to `getFooAtIndex`, then it can be done in one line:

```
for(Foo index = 0, foo = getFooAtIndex(0); foo != NULL_FOO_VALUE; foo = getFooAtIndex(++index)) {
    // do stuff with foo. It's safe to use continue
}
```